# Android Wear Data Syncing Issues

Tags: android, synchronization, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, watchface

I have created a watch face that contains a config screen on the phone and a simplified config screen on the wearable.  This is the layout of my project:

- MobileModule
- WearModule
- UtilModule (contains util class that retrieves data from Google API)

The Config screen on the phone works properly retrieving and storing data that is received on the watch face.  When I change the background or images there, the changes show on the watch face.  The problem is with the config class on the wearable.  For some reason whenever launch it and retrieve the DataMap using the same class in UtilModule that I do on the phone app, it always retrieves an empty map.  Can someone please explain to me why I am an idiot?

Comment: You might want to check the [sample](https://developer.android.com/samples/WatchFace/index.html) provided by Google that show how to communicate the configuration change to the watch face activity, `DigitalWatchFaceWearableConfigActivity` and `DigitalWatchFaceUtil` classes. Also check how you implemented [Wearable Data Layer API](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html) to sync any changes in your watchface. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I had free time to work on this project again.  I did look through the sample and do not see an issue.